# Git adding to a parent branch

Tags: git

I have a remote git respository with A and B branches. A is the parent of B. They are both empty at the moment.

I need to get the same code into A & B, without merging them. Without realizing which branch I was on, I did a git commit in branch B. When I checkout branch A and try to do the add/commit there, I get a "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" message. How can I get the files committed in this branch?

Yes, I realize this is a strange way of doing things. I'm not looking for commentary on the way the repository is organized.

Answer (score 2):

branch in git is just pointer to commit, thus when you checkout A, the commit to branch B won't be there. You can do `git cherry-pick B` to pick the last commit from B to A.

I guess your repo looks like,

```
 A--> C0 <-- B
```

at the beginning, then you checkout B and commit, which makes it look like,

```
 A--> C0 
       |
      C1  <-- B
```

let me know if that's not the case

Comment: Thanks, I'm a total git n00b and very confused on this. When I checkout A, the files that I committed in B are still there. If I remove them in A, then a git status on A shows the removal. Am I correct in assuming that since these branches were both empty, that what I put in B will show up in A (until they diverge in edits/changes)?

Comment: divergence doesn't really matter, A and B are just two pointers to your commits.

Comment: @Maxthecat: Wow, you are definitely confused :-)  Branches are not "empty", nor are they "full", they're just labels, with each branch name pointing to one commit.  You should work your way through (at least some of) the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), which is free on line.